# Odd Meta character showing up

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I am at a loss here. After updating servers a few months ago we finally started working on an error where our characters weren't showing up correctly (after updating the entire site to the new php). We have chatrooms where users input their information, and displays on another page (the whochat) This seems to be working, except that it puts an extra character at the end of the name.

[image]

[image]

I've gone in and THOUGHT I changed all meta tags to UTF-8 but for whatever reason, everything displays correctly except that one extra symbol.

[image]

Comment: What font are you using? The diamond symbol usually indicates that the font doesn't have the particular character(s) in it's set and the browser replaces the unknown letter with the diamond character.

Comment: That was copy and pasted from notepad which I had currently set to 'georgia', and copy and pasted that in. Its happening to quite a few people, but only with certain characters that are missing.

Comment: so I swapped and pasted from the notepad from new times roman, and it aligned it the way it should be, but still seeing that daimond. I'm not sure why. the spaces after the registered symbol are all alt codes, +0160 to create that space which displays fine, until the very end. was trying to attach another screenshot.

Comment: All tech stacks have eventually migrated to Unicode, normally UTF-8. Your application is probably using some single byte encoding such as US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 or whatever, but failing to set the encoding because, at the time, it was the default. The effort that really makes sense is to migrate everything to UTF-8 and ensure you are actively declaring the correct encoding everywhere.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro we're testing that now in moving things back, part of our database from before our transition does seem to be in ISO-8859-1 so we're ensuring the entire thing is properly encoded as we've already doublechecked the pages and hopefully will marry it all together. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

that might be a special character came in while you pasted that, remove that or any symbolic special character in code, also an ASCII code is the reason of this.

Comment: For clarification its been copy and pasted numerous times with and without special characters, with ASCII code, with ALT codes (which are the spaces around the name) which we used to have no issue with previously, so I'm uncertain if I'm using the wrong tag (UTF-8) to cover them all

Comment: try to use this meta element, " <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> " if the problem is with the UTF-8 then it will convert it to iso-***.

Comment: also the diamond question mark also gone by this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-32" />